# Cannot install google-cloud-videointelligence

Tags: python, video-intelligence-api

I have an error, when I install google-cloud-video intelligence. ERROR: Could not install packages due to an Environment Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

> 'C:\Users\Supervisor\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\google\cloud\videointelligence_v1\gapic\transports\__pycache__\video_intelligence_service_grpc_transport.cpython-37.pyc'

On stackoverflow I found several comments that I should install virtualenv before.

When I install virtualenv and after them I set virtualenv a error occured: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

> 'C:\Users\Supervisor\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'.

I don't know what I can do? I have test so much and investate so much time but I can't install google-cloud-videointelligence.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your path is messed up. I believe you are on windows. Make sure that your virtualenv is installing at the right spot and that the multiple version of python you have have the right ordering in your PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the installation is on Windows. I think, I have set virtualenv on the correct path >c:\users\supervisor\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\Scripts<

That are the first two lines as result when I start virtualenv with the path declaration:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>virtualenv c:\users\supervisor\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\Scripts
Using base prefix 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0'

In the last line appears an error:
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\Supervisor\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'

Using base prefix 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0'

I think the definition on >Using base prefix< is wrong, but I don't no how I can change this definition.